# How to connect IR sensor ( Infrared detector/receiver )?

Tags: sensor, identification, infrared, phototransistor

Would you give me a hand ?

I have an IR sensor with 3 pins. It looks like the one in the picture, and I did not find any datasheet for it on the internet. actually, I have 3 questions :

1- I want to identify its pins ? (Where can I put the positive, ground ...etc. ?)

2- How to connect it with a visible LED so that when the IR sensor receive IR Rays, the LED lights up ?

3- Should I transmit IR Rays with a specific frequency ? or just connect IR LED to the power only ?

[image]

Comment: Helping you is quite difficult. Where did you buy/found this receiver? Can you provide a photo of it?

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
I found it in an receiver (TV). this is the picture : http://i.stack.imgur.com/H91t9.jpg

Comment: A photo of the pcb where you took it from is the only way to be extra sure of the pinout. These guys have two power pins (Vcc and ground) and a digital output. They expect a IR signal pulsed at some 10s of kHz modulated by your information signal.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :) 
is there any way to identify the Vcc and ground ?

Comment: *Read the datasheet*.

Comment: @user2824371 - is the part number on the back of the part "38B 3V K532"? I can't find that, and google is usually pretty good with part numbers. As Vladimir Cravero explained, there are several different pinouts, so a part number is important to get the right datasheet. Detailed, closeup, photo's of the PCB *might* help, especially if you indicate which way round the part was connected. However the part number would be easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an IR receiver that looks like yours. The one I have is equivalent to this TSOP38238 from [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor)::
[image]

This IR detector demodulates a modulated IR at 38kHz and provides a digital decoded signal at the output.

Assuming it's the same one; here's the pinout:
[image]

The DATASHEET is available [here](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/tsop382.pdf) (TSOP38238).

Head over to [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor) for all the details including how to connect to a visible LED:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a method to find the pin outs ,my method is by luck though but is quite easy if you got the sensor out of a PCB of an old electronic if its able to power up. if can power it up do a continuity test find in the 3 pins which is ground after you found the ground mark it if your able to or remember it and find another pin with a voltage of 3.3 volts and that it u found the pin out hope i help someone

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much like a TSOP382xx from Vishay, available at Adafruit:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266 You can find a datasheet there also.

The carrier frequency depends on which model you have, the last two digits in the part number.

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the block diagram above pin 1 is your output (far left on your picture). The receiver sinks pin 1 when the correct carrier is detected. But it can only sink a maximum of 5mA so you must limit the diode current if you hook one up directly to the output. I would use a buffer stage of some sorts. Hint: you could probably make one yourself with a PNP transistor.